# R extracting the frequencies

Tags: r, data.table, frequency

I am trying to get the frequencies but my ids are repeating. Here is a sample data:

```
id <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
gender <- c("m","m","f","f","m","m")
score <- c(10,5,10,5,10,5)
data <- data.frame("id"=id,"gender"=gender, "score"=score)

> data
  id gender score
1  1      m    10
2  1      m     5
3  2      f    10
4  2      f     5
5  3      m    10
6  3      m     5
```

I would like to get the frequencies of the gender categories but I have repeating ids. When I run this code below:

```
gender<-as.data.frame(table(data$gender))
> gender
  Var1 Freq
1    f    2
2    m    4
```

The frequency should be female = 1, male =2. it should look like this below:

```
> gender
  Var1 Freq
1    f    1
2    m    2
```

How can I get this considering the id information?

Comment: You first need to uniquely identify id-gender combinations.  Then make your table. 
 Here's one way:  `table(unique(data[ , c("id", "gender"))$gender)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R

```
rowSums(table(data$gender,data$id)!=0)
f m 
1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data.table::uniqueN` to count the number of unique ids per gender group

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[, .(Freq = uniqueN(id)), gender]

#    gender Freq
# 1:      m    2
# 2:      f    1
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea from @IceCreamToucan with `dplyr`:

```
data %>%
 group_by(gender) %>%
 summarise(freq = n_distinct(id))

  gender  freq
  <fct>  <int>
1 f          1
2 m          2
```

Comment: for some reason, I getting the total freq, rather than freq for each category with your code.

Comment: That's strange. Try to update to the newest version of `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1):

Being late to the party, I was quite surprised about the sophisticated answers which use grouping or `rowSums()`.

In base R, I would

1. remove the duplicate `id` rows from the data.frame by subsetting with `duplicated(id)`,
2. apply `table()` on the `gender` column.

So, the code is

```
table(data[duplicated(data$id), "gender"])
```

> ```
> f m 
> 1 2
> ```